# Basic string compare causing crashes

Tags: c, arduino

I have this global

```
const char PROTOCOL_SET_WIFI_CONNECTION[]= "setWifi";

//or this one
//#define PROTOCOL_SET_WIFI_CONNECTION "setWifi"
```

Then when i am trying to compare strings i get many problems ( hardware problems such as crashes )

```
char *header = strtok (incomingData,":");
if (strcmp (header,PROTOCOL_SET_WIFI_CONNECTION ) == 0)
```

//do stuff

1. whats wrong with my comparison( with out this "if" everything is good)
2. which one is preferred -define or const ? (MCU)

Comment: You don't check if `header` is `NULL`...

Comment: What is `incommingData`? Are you sure that the colon is in the string and `strtok` doesn't return `NULL`? Have you actually checked with a debugger that the crash happens where you think it is?

Comment: I am sure its not null ( i am checking if its null long before i am returning this value.) moreover , this value is valid even when the problems occur. only when i remove this if , things are working as expected .

Comment: and again, only removing the "if" statement solving the problem , thats it. the other strtok command is not causing any problem .

Comment: It's impossible to say anything with the code you show, or without knowing what the variable values are. Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, and also include the values of all variables when the crash happens, possibly with a debugger stack trace as well.

Comment: BTW you can also use `strstr()` to find where `"setWifi"` appears in `incomingData` without using `strtok()`.

Comment: From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html): *These functions cannot be used on constant strings.* and *The strtok() function uses a static buffer while parsing, so it's not thread safe.*.

Comment: @dbc so you cant compare to a const string ? you have to hard code your strings inside the code? its an ugly code isn't it ? :)

Comment: The problem isn't `strcmp` it's `strtok` which modifies its 1st argument and also uses a static buffer internally.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this

> Once the terminating null character of str is found in a call to strtok, all subsequent calls to this function (with a null pointer as the first argument) return a null pointer.

[strtok reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

Try checking if the string is NULL right at before the erroring line?